# Does there exist a closed form expression of $d_r(n,k)$?

Tags: combinatorics

The number $d_r(n,k)$ is the number of permutations of $n$ having exactly $k$ cycles all of which are of length $\ge r$.

I know that the function can be given by:

$d_r(n,k)=(n-1)d_r(n-1,k)+(n-1)_{r-1}d_r(n-r,k-1).$

But is there a closed form expression?

Thanks.

Comment: there might be a typo ($r-1$) in the last term

Comment: @suissidle I got it from [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PermutationCycle.html)

Comment: Given that Mathworld doesn't mention a closed form expression for the [simplest case](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StirlingNumberoftheFirstKind.html), it's safe to assume that the best you can hope for is a generating function or a finite sum.